# Representing a complex object in contentful

Tags: json, contentful

I'm currently evaluating [contentful](https://www.contentful.com/) as a potential cms for a project. I've been playing around with the json api, which is great, but I'm having trouble representing anything more complex than a flat object data structure as a content type.

The workaround I've found is to create a separate entity and reference it, which works, but makes things quite a bit more complicated (far more entities, requires additional publishing, etc.).

As discussed by contentful [here](https://www.contentful.com/blog/2015/02/17/content-trees-tags-and-facets-in-contentful/), this approach works great for relating content, but that's a different use case. I simply want to create a piece of content like the following:

```
{
  "item": "value",
  "subitem": {
    "item": "value"
  }
}
```

Is there another approach to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

So what you are talking about is exactly the same issues we had when building one of our applications.

To get around this, we wrote a small npm module that parses these complex content types pretty easily.

Check it out here: https://github.com/remedyhealth/contentpull

If you want to see the parts talking specifically about the parsing, we wrote a simple tonic notebook to show this: https://tonicdev.com/mrsteele/contentpull

(the parser section is towards the bottom)

Let me know if that helps at all, and please feel free to fork and improve if you have any good recommendations.